When is the type of j->quals either a sublink, or an and-clause, or a not-clause?
if ((j = convert_ANY_sublink_to_join(root, sublink,
                                         available_rels1)) != NULL)
    {
        /* Yes; insert the new join node into the join tree */
        j->larg = *jtlink1;
        *jtlink1 = (Node *) j;
        /* Recursively process pulled-up jointree nodes */
        j->rarg = pull_up_sublinks_jointree_recurse(root,
                                                    j->rarg,
                                                    &child_rels);

        /*
         * Now recursively process the pulled-up quals.  Any inserted
         * joins can get stacked onto either j->larg or j->rarg,
         * depending on which rels they reference.
         */
        j->quals = pull_up_sublinks_qual_recurse(root,
                                                 j->quals,
                                                 &j->larg,
                                                 available_rels1,
                                                 &j->rarg,
                                                 child_rels);
        /* Return NULL representing constant TRUE */
        return NULL;
    }

above is a snippet excerted from function pull_up_sublinks_qual_recurse() of postgresql 14.4.
pull_up_sublinks_qual_recurse() will recursively call itself when convert_ANY_sublink_to_join() return nonnull. But only when the type of its second argument is either a sublink, or an and-clause, or a not-clause will pull_up_sublinks_qual_recurse() do something meaningful.
I just cannot figure out a sql query where j->quals is either a sublink, or an and-clause, or a not-clause immediately after returning from convert_ANY_sublink_to_join(). Can anybody show me an example?
select a 
from A 
where a in (select b from B); 

In this query, after returning from convert_ANY_sublink_to_join(), j->quals is a node of type OpExpr.
I cannot figure out a query that can make j->quals a node of type SubLink, or and-clause, or not-clause. I highly doubt whether the recursive call of pull_up_sublinks_qual_recurse() here is necessary.

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

for example, select a from A where a in (select b from B);  in this query, after returning from convert_ANY_sublink_to_join(), j->quals is a node of type OpExpr. I cannot figure out a query that can make  j->quals a node of type SubLink, or and-clause, or not-clause. I highly doubt whether the recursive call of pull_up_sublinks_qual_recurse() here is necessary
